# What do we call a group of stage actors?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

What do we call a group of stage actors and actresses, who join together in one team to present theatrical performance? 
An image is attached for illustration [image]

Comment: You don't use the word troupe?

Comment: I think you can simply refer to them as the cast of the play.

Comment: It would not work in the context I am working on.

Comment: @user186499 what does not work? _troupe_ or _cast_?

Comment: The company.  What context are you working on?

Comment: a drama of actors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they come together just for a single performance, they are called the [*cast*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cast#cast_Noun_200) of the play. However, if they regularly perform together, they may be called a [***troupe***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/troupe) or [***repertory company***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/repertory_company).

*Troupe* generally applies to groups that travel from one venue to another, and may sometimes be used for groups that tour for only one show. *Repertory company* refers specifically to a group that performs multiple successive shows together, and usually has a stationary home theatre (though repertory companies may also tour). From Oxford Dictionaries:

> **cast<sup>2</sup>** NOUN
>   *treated as singular or plural* The actors taking part in a play, film, or other production.
>
> **troupe** NOUN
>   A group of dancers, actors, or other entertainers who tour to different venues.
>
> **repertory company** NOUN
>   A theatrical company that performs plays from its repertoire for regular, short periods of time, moving on from one play to another.

Comment: Or just ***company*** for short.

Comment: Very nice answer, laying out the options and their different uses.

Comment: A theatre company doesn't have to be'repertory'. If they are resident in a single place and offer different performances regularly then they are just a "theatre company".